# Trim last "," delimiter of a string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, trim

This is my code:

```
With ad.Tables(2)
    For i As Integer = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1
        If .Rows(i)("name") & "" <> "" Then
            temp &= .Rows(i)("name") & ", "
        End If
    Next
End With
temp = temp.Trim(",")
testing &= "&Name=" & temp & vbCrLf
```

With this is get a comma in the end of the string. But if I do

```
temp = temp.Trim.Trim(",")
```

all commas are deleted.

How do I keep all commas and only delete the last one?

Comment: Please use the Code format in your question (the 101010 thing in your formatting toolbox :) )

Answer (score 31):

```
temp = temp.TrimEnd(CChar(","))
```

That will do it and I think it is the easiest way.

Comment: This works only if the character before the last is different than comma. In many cases (for instance in a .csv file) there are a lot of repeated commas at the ending of the file. I prefer the `temp = temp.Trim().Remove(temp.Length - 1)` which is also simple in reading.

Comment: You didn't give any examples of your data and if you've got multiple commas, you need to rethink your if test. This is a great answer for removing the last delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I added Trim() to account for unwanted whitespace so that the last non-whitespace character that is a comma is removed.  temp = temp.Trim().TrimEnd(CChar(","))

Answer (score 16):

```
temp = temp.Trim().Substring(0, temp.Length - 1)
```

or

```
temp = temp.Trim().Remove(temp.Length - 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the Trim/extra character if you set a delimiter within the loop

```
Dim delimiter as string = ""
For i As Integer = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1
   If .Rows(i)("name") & "" <> "" Then
      temp &= delimiter & .Rows(i)("name")
      delimiter = ","
   End If
Next
```

Comment: I removed the If check from your post because it is actually slower.  The runtime is smart enough to optimize away the assignment like this, but it has to evaluate the if condition on every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The `Trim()` function has a `Char()` (static array of characters) parameter on it, you don't need to pass a `Char` explicitly.

```
' VB.Net Version
", Hello ^_^ ^_^ ,,, , ,,   ,, ,".Trim({" "c, ","c})

//C# version
", Hello ^_^ ^_^ ,,, , ,,   ,, ,".Trim({' ', ','})
```

Would produce the output

```
"Hello ^_^ ^_^"
```

The multi-parameter `.Trim()` removes the specified characters from both the beginning and the end of the string.  If you want to only trim out the beginning or the end, use `.TrimStart()` or `.TrimEnd()` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
dim AlarmStr as string="aaa , bbb , ccc ,  "
AlarmStr = AlarmStr.Remove(AlarmStr.LastIndexOf(","))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please properly format your answers.

Comment: thank you.. i will format it well next time..this is my first reply in the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the loop is done before adding the last comma. #cleaner

```
While dr.Read
   For c As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
       s.Append(dr(c).ToString.Trim)

       'This line checks if the loop is ending before adding a comma           
       If (c < dr.FieldCount - 1) Then s.Append(",")

   Next
   s.Append(vbCrLf)
End While
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, that based on the OP's code sample, nobody suggested to use `String.Join` or build an output with `StringBuilder`

```
Dim names As New List(Of String)
With ad.Tables(2)
    For i As Integer = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1
        ' DataRow("columnName").ToString() returns value or empty string if value is DbNull
        If .Rows(i)("name").ToString() <> "" Then
           names.Add(.Rows(i)("name"))
        End If
    Next
End With

Dim temp As String = String.Join(", ", names)
testing &= "&Name=" & temp & vbCrLf
```

With LINQ and `DataRow` extension method `.Field(Of T)` code will look simpler

```
Dim names = ad.Tables(2).
    AsEnumerable().
    Select(row => row.Field<String>("name")).
    Where(name => String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) = False)

Dim temp As String = String.Join(", ", names)
testing &= "&Name=" & temp & vbCrLf
```

If you go further you can(should) use `StringBuilder` for building a string and use `Aggregate` method to build string from the collection

Answer (score -2):

```
temp = temp.TrimEnd()
```

this trims the trailing spaces from a string.

Comment: Yes, but the question was stripping the last delimiter

Answer (score -2):

I know that a little bit odd, but I found this works for me:

Visual Basic:

Every time: mystring = "today, I love go out , , , ," (less than five commas and spaces)

```
mystring.Trim.TrimEnd(",").Trim.TrimEnd(",").Trim.TrimEnd(",").Trim.TrimEnd(",").Trim.TrimEnd(",")
```

Comment: In your example, you should use a loop